# Entity Framework - implementing one-to-many foreign key relationship in Seed() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I have the following classes:

**Landlord**

```
[Table("Landlord")]
public class Landlord : UserProfile
{
    public static int LandlordProfileViews { get; set; }

    // A Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties
    [ForeignKey("ResidentialPropertyId")]
    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialProperty> ResidentialProperties { get; set; }

}
```

**ResidentialProperty**

```
[Table("ResidentialProperty")]
public class ResidentialProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ResidentialPropertyId { get; set; }
    // ...

    // A ResidentialProperty has 1 Landlord
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

A Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties, so the association is one-to-many. I'm trying to add test data to my database using the `Seed()` method. My problem is I don't know how to define the many end of the relationship in the method. The following is what I've tried:

```
var residentialProperties = new List<ResidentialProperty>
{
    // Property 1 associated with LandLord 1
    new ResidentialProperty { /* properties */ },
    // ...
 }

var landlords = new List<Landlord>
 {
    new Landlord { /* properties */ ResidentialProperties = residentialProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResidentialPropertyId == 1) },
    // ...
 }
```

The `ResidentialProperties = residentialProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResidentialPropertyId == 1)` gives a 'Cannot implicitly convert type ResidentialProperty to ICollection < ResidentialProperty > error.

How do you implement one-to-many relationships in the Seed() method?

EDIT:

I've added the following in my context class to try and implement this type of relationship: *A Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties. A ResidentialProperty can only have one Landlord*:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Landlord>()
            .HasMany(x => x.ResidentialProperties)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ResidentialPropertyId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ResidentialProperty>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile);
```

I'm still getting this error:

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not
>   valid in Role 'Landlord_ResidentialProperties_Target' in relationship
>   'Landlord_ResidentialProperties'. Because the Dependent Role refers to
>   the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '1'..

Still at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a list of ResidentalProperties. The query you have `ResidentialProperties = residentialProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResidentialPropertyId == 1)` is only returning a single ResidentialProperty enitity. Just do `ResidentialProperties = residentialProperties`

Edit: You can do the many to one setup through a single configuration. You also have to specify the foreign key.

```
            //ResidentialProperty has 1 Landlord ,
            //Landlord has many ResidentialProperties
            modelBuilder.Entity<ResidentialProperty>().HasRequired(a=> a.UserProfile)
                .WithMany(c=> c.ResidentialProperties)
                .HasForeignKey(a=> a.UserId);
```

Comment: That gets rid of the error, however, when I run the update database command I get the following error from the package manager: "Unable to determine the principal end of the 'MyNamespace.Models.Landlord_ResidentialProperties' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.' This is kind of why I thought I had to specify that property 1 belonged to landlord 1. Would explicitly adding a PK (in Seed() method) for each ResidentialProperty solve it?

Comment: No, you dont need to add a PK. It will get automatically added when you save the context. Also make sure you have a reference to Landlord in the RentalProperty.

Comment: Please see edited question (added reference to Lanlord in ResidentialProperty). When the reference is added, I get the error (after tying to update via package manager console) "The navigation property 'UserId' is not a declared property on type 'ResidentialProperty'." I originally had that reference in. Is this a unique kind of relationship, as a Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties, but a ResidentialPropertiy can only (in the application's scope) belong to one Landlord? Can this relationship be achieved with annotations? Or do I need to use Fluent API?

Comment: You configure the relationship via Fluent API. See this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: I've tried to implement the relationship using Fluent API as suggested, but still no luck. Please see edit. Do you know how to implement such a relationship using Fluent API? Would be much appreciated if you could provide an answer if you do. My model classes are exactly as-is in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I try that configuration, when I go .WithMany(...) I'm not getting the option to select ResidentialProperties. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: The option to go .HasForeignKey(...) is also not available. I've also read something about circular dependency which can cause this error - would that have anything to with this? I don't understand why something that should be so simple is taking so long to implement.

Comment: Probably because the type of UserProfile is UserProfile and not Landlord.

Comment: I've tried to change it to Landlord, but it's not available to select. Completely stumped.

Comment: Try making UserId virtual.

Comment: Making UserId virtual made no difference. I edited my question with something else I have tried, but it's lead to another error...

Comment: Another thing you can try is to remove the [ForeignKey("ResidentialPropertyId")] attribute.

Comment: I tried that already, thanks though. I'm getting to the point where I feel I may have to start over from scratch, nothing is ever easy using VS.

Comment: Found out what my problem was. I had navigation property on many side as that of base class when it should have been of derived class i.e. Landlord. There's a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940907/entity-framework-code-first-table-per-type-inheritance-implementing-a-one if you're interested. Since you pointed out that I was incorrect in my initial approach and said I needed to return a list of properties, I'll mark  your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the model relationships you are asking for.

```
public class Landlord : UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get;set;} //If you named this "LandlorId" you wouldn't need the [Key]

//this convention will wire up to the otherside    
public virtual ICollection<ResidentialProperty> ResidentialProperties { get; set; }

}

public class ResidentialProperty{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get;set;}

   //this convention will wire up to the otherside
   public LandLordId {get;set;}
   public Landlord Landlord {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'm using table-per-type inheritance so my navigation property in ResidentialProperty points to UserProfile (Landlord inherits from UserProfile). If you look at my question, you will see that I have navigation properties on both sides. My problem is trying to implement the relationship I outlined in my comment under Ryan Byrne's answer.