# Entity Framework / code first / table-per-type inheritance - implementing a one-to-many association between a derived class and a concrete class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm using MVC4 in VS2012, and I'm following a table-per-type inheritance approach. I'm trying to use the `Seed()` method to add data to my database.

I have the following classes:

**LandLord**

```
[Table("Landlord")]
public class Landlord : UserProfile
{
    // A Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties
    [ForeignKey("ResidentialPropertyId")]
    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialProperty> ResidentialProperties { get; set; }
}
```

**ResidentialProperty**

```
[Table("ResidentialProperty")]
public class ResidentialProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ResidentialPropertyId { get; set; }

    // A ResidentialProperty has 1 Landlord
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } 

}
```

So `Landlord` inherits from `UserProfile`, hence there is no PK property in `Landlord.`

The relationship I'm trying to implement is as follows:

- *A `Landlord` can have many `ResidentialProperties` (1:n)*
- *A `ResidentialProperty` can (in the application's scope) have one `Landlord` (1:1)*

I thought the way I had my models configured would be enough to run the `update-database` command from package manager successfully, and add what I have in my `Seed()` method to my database. This wasn't the case, I got the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of the 'LetLord.Models.ResidentialProperty_UserProfile' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

After reading around I realised that the relationship I wanted to create needed to be implemented using Fluent API, so I tried the following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Landlord>()
            .HasMany(x => x.ResidentialProperties)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ResidentialPropertyId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ResidentialProperty>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile);
```

When I try to execute the `update-database` command via package manager I get the following error:

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Landlord_ResidentialProperties_Target' in relationship 'Landlord_ResidentialProperties'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

I'm completely at a loss as to how to remedy my problem. I've spent an awful lot of time stuck on this, which is very frustrating as it is something that I feel should be accomplished easily. If anyone has the solution, I'd be very appreciative if you could share it with me.

**EDIT** - output of exception thrown from the first error mentioned above:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'LetLord.Models.ResidentialProperty_Landlord' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'LetLord.Models.ResidentialProperty_Landlord' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.RegisterEntityReferentialConstraints(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry, Boolean currentValues)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.RegisterReferentialConstraints(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.PullModifiedEntriesFromStateManager()
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>      at LetLord.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(LetLordContext context) in c:\Users\Home\Desktop\LetLord\LetLord\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 83

**EDIT** - solution:

Entities should be as per Ladislav's answer below, my mistake was making navigation property on the many side of the base class, and not the derived class.

My next error was ordering of entities in my `Seed()` method. I've added below what they should be like, this applies especially when adding entities with associations.

```
    protected override void Seed(LetLord.Models.LetLordContext context)
    {

        try
        {

            #region Landlords

            // create a list of landlords first - a landlord can have many residential properties, make this  = new List<ResidentialProperty>()
            var landlords = new List<Landlord>
        {
            // landlord 1
            new Landlord { UserName="Frank",     FirstName="Frank",   LastName="O'Sullivan", Email="a@a.com", AccountType=(int)AccountType.Landlord, ResidentialProperties = new List<ResidentialProperty>() }

            // ...
        };
            landlords.ForEach(l => context.UserProfile.AddOrUpdate(l));
            context.SaveChanges();

            #endregion

            #region ResidentialProperties

            // then create a list of properties
            var residentialProperties = new List<ResidentialProperty>
        {
            // Property 1 associated with LandLord 1
            new ResidentialProperty { PropTypeValue=(int)PropertyType.Detached, Description="Some description...", NumberOfBedrooms="4", NumberOfReceptionRooms="2", NumberOfBathrooms="2", HasBackGarden=true, HasFrontGarden=true, HasSecureParking=false, IsDisabledFriendly=false, DateAdded=DateTime.Now, Landlord = landlords.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 11) } // in my case, user 11 is landlord 1

            // ... 
        };
            residentialProperties.ForEach(rp => context.ResidentialProperty.AddOrUpdate(rp));
            context.SaveChanges(); 

            #endregion

            // then add our list of properties to our list of landlords
            landlords[0].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[0]);
            landlords[1].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[1]);
            landlords[2].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[2]);
            landlords[3].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[3]);
            landlords[4].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[4]);
            landlords[5].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[5]);
            landlords[6].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[6]);
            landlords[7].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[7]);
            landlords[8].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[8]);
            landlords[9].ResidentialProperties.Add(residentialProperties[9]);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string lines = ex.ToString();
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\error.txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        }
```

When I tried to run `update-database` after fixing code as above, I ran into this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ResidentialProperty_dbo.Landlord_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\HOME\DESKTOP\LETLORD\LETLORD\APP_DATA\LETLORD.MDF", table "dbo.Landlord", column 'UserId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

After a quick search I found that this error was being caused (I think) as there was already data in my database. Dropping and recreating the database got around this and when I ran the `Seed()` method again data was added successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Landlord can have multiple properties and property can have <strike>multiple</strike> one landlord the model should look like:

```
[Table("Landlord")]
public class Landlord : UserProfile
{
    // A Landlord can have many ResidentialProperties
    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialProperty> ResidentialProperties { get; set; }
}

[Table("ResidentialProperty")]
public class ResidentialProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ResidentialPropertyId { get; set; }

    // A ResidentialProperty has 1 Landlord
    // Foreign key is on many side and it contains value of primary key on one side
    // In your case FK must contain value of property's landlord
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    // ForeignKey attribute pairs navigation property on many side with foreign key propety 
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer to my question. I'm not sure if you misread my question, or else made a mistake in your answer - but in the scope of my application a ResidentialProperty can only be associated with one Landlord. Am I correct in saying that you mistyped in the opening line?

Comment: I'm sorry - I mistyped the opening line but rest of the answer should show your real case.

Comment: I've implemented exactly as per your solution, but I'm still getting the error "Unable to determine primary key..." when I don't include the Fluent API as per my question. When I include it again, I get the second error in my question again. Any ideas as to what's causing this? I printed the exception thrown to a text file and included it in my edit - not sure if will be of any use.

Comment: Ladislav, based on my question above - do have any idea as to why I'm still getting the errors when I try to run update database from package manager? Does the exception I provided in my edit offer any more insight? I'd be very grateful if the issue could be resolved as it's stopping me progressing with my project. Thanks.

Comment: It is something wrong in your `Seed` method. Can you add content of your `Seed` method to your question?

Comment: Added Seed code to my question - the line the exception is thrown at is just after the list residentialProperties (there's a comment beside it). In case you're wondering, I've added 10 tenant (UserId 1 -10) and 10 landlords (UserId 11 - 20). Properties 1 - 10 are associated with landlords 11 - 20 (property 1 with landlord 11, 2 with 12 and so on).

Comment: Looks like you are adding properties with connection to landlords before you add land lords (land lords list is empty).

Comment: Ladislav, thanks a lot for helping me to resolve the issue, I'm now able to run update-database and entities are being added to database as required. My first error was making navigation property on many side that of base class and not derived class. My second error was the ordering of items as you describe in comment above, and one other thing which I'll include in a final edit on my question.